# Dataframe divide series on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to divide each column of the matrix `df1` into a single column of the matrix `df2`. To get a matrix with dimension `df1` (3*2).

I need a result: dataframe[[1/6, 2/7, 3/8], [3/6, 4/7, 5,8]]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]], index = ['a','b'], columns = ['i','ii','iii'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[6],[7],[8]], index = ['a','b','c'], columns = ['i'])

df1.div(df2, axis = 'columns')
=> does not work

for i in range(0,2)
    a = df1[df1.columns[i]] / df2
=> summarizes the result in one column
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: divide column-wise? Sure?

Comment: I need a result: dataframe[[1/6, 2/7, 3/8], [3/6, 4/7, 5,8]]

Comment: Okay, so you want to divide the rows in df1

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote all answers here @KrDanRod :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.values/ df2.values.T, columns=df1.columns)

       i        ii      iii
0  0.166667  0.285714  0.375
1  0.500000  0.571429  0.625
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by `Series` converted to array by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) or [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) for pandas 0.24+:

```
df = df1.div(df2['i'].values)
#pandas 0.24+
#df = df1.div(df2['i'].to_numpy())
print (df)
          i        ii    iii
a  0.166667  0.285714  0.375
b  0.500000  0.571429  0.625
```

Comment: Pandas documentation sucks. Your post is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

with Series :

```
s = pd.Series(df2.values.flatten().tolist(), index=df1.columns)
print(df1.div(s))
```

output :

```
          i        ii    iii
a  0.166667  0.285714  0.375
b  0.500000  0.571429  0.625
```