# Divide Pandas Dataframe by Series - why does it work?

Tags: pandas

I've come across something that while looking at how to normalize data on datacamp.com

In one of the exercises it was said that to normalize a dataframe df one should do like this

```
normalized_df = df / df.mean()
```

My question is: why does this work? Why does Pandas know here to divide columnwise?

Thanks

Edit: This post [Dataframe divide series on pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168120/dataframe-divide-series-on-pandas) does not answer the question I am posting. I merely states what to do. I want to know why it works.

Comment: All the information you need is in that post.  TL;DR The result of `df.mean()` produces a `pandas.Series` object whose index matches the `columns` of `df`.  When dividing `df / df.mean()`, Pandas sees the index of `df.mean()` and matches it with the `columns` of `df` by default.  That is how it knows.

Comment: it works because of  df.mean(axis=0) which is the default value.

Comment: Thanks, piRSquared!